# How to apply strong pigeonhole principle to this question?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle, coloring

For each $r\geq 1$, let $L(r,n)$ denote the integer for which given any sequence of length $L(r,n)$, and any $r$-coloring of the elements of the sequence, there exists a monochromatic increasing sequence of length $n+1$ or a monochromatic decreasing sequence of length $n+1$,  but there exists a sequence of length $L(r,n)-1$ and an $r$-coloring of that sequence which has no monochromatic increasing or decreasing sequence of length $n+1$. So, $L(1,n)=n^2+1$ for all $n$. Find $L(r,n)$ for all $r,n\geq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Given an $r$-coloring of $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_m\rangle$, you can consider each of the $r$ monochromatic subsequences independently. You need at least one of them to be long enough to ensure that it has a monotone subsequence of length $n+1$, and you know what $L(1,n)$ is.

Comment: Is the final answer $rn^{2}+1$? Because if we consider all r monochromatic subsequence  s, and if all r of them has length $n^{2}$, then we know there doesn't exist monotone subsequence of length $n+1$. And thus, we add one extra element and that will suffice?

Comment: @KingHo: That’s right, though your explanation isn’t *quite* right. If all $r$ of them have length $n^2$, then it’s **possible** that there is no monotone subsequence of length $n+1$, so we cannot guarantee that there is one, but adding one extra element means that at least one color has $n^2+1$ representatives, and then we **can** guarantee a monochromatic monotone subsequence of length $n+1$.

Comment: i see what you mean. Think of the r-color as r boxes and the size of sequence as objects. Then by strong pigeonhole principle, we need r((n^{2}+1)-1)+1 elements. Thank you, that makes sense now